# changes to mercurial repository

Tags: android, mercurial, tortoisehg

I maintain Merucrial repository for an Android application / Java based sources with package name com.company.app. As with any Android application I had the following directory structure, at directory called **origProj**

```
+--assets  
+--res  
+--src  
     +-- com  
       +-- company   
          +-- app
```

Now I have to change the package name to net.company2.app. The name of the java source files does not change (only the package statement in each file changes). I want to continue using the same repository. I do not want to loose the history/information associated with various commits I have made in the past. How do I do this?

I made a copy of the **origProj** directory (using Windows file explorer) to **newProj**- and changed the sub-directories to reflect the new package name -

```
+--assets  
+--res  
+--src  
   +-- net  
      +-- company2   
         +-- app
```

It all worked, but when I open the repository to "commit" changes I made, the files listed are messy - I mean there are entries with the older directory structure. It doesn't surprise me because I realize I did not do it the "Mercurial" way. What is the correct way to do this? I looked into the mercurial Definitive guide - I could not locate the sections relevant to what I am doing- maybe the language/terms are something I could not relate to. Please help.

Comment: I came across hg purge --print - but then I could not run this option. I get the message "hg: unknown command 'purge'". I have hg 1.5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `hg mv` of the classes to be refactored, commit, then refactor the  classes with the new package name and commit again.  `purge` is not what you want, it removes the files and directories not under version control.